# Assignment to struct member after inline cast to struct fails in Linaro version > 4.4?

Tags: android, compiler-errors, kernel, arm, cross-compiling

Why is it that the following line of kernel source:

```
((struct fb_var_screeninfo) (s5ptv_status.fb->var)).bits_per_pixel =
    ((struct fb_var_screeninfo) (fb->var)).bits_per_pixel;
```

compiles normally in the GNU ARM toolchain from 2010q1, and in the Linaro toolchain v4.4, but fails with the following error when using the Linaro toolchain v4.5 or v4.6?

```
drivers/media/video/samsung/tv20/s5p_stda_grp.c:614:12: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Did something change from 4.4 to 4.5 that made this syntax invalid?

Comment: Here's my github link, if you think that context might matter: https://github.com/kynalvarus/sch-i510_kernel/blob/gingerbread/drivers/media/video/samsung/tv20/s5p_stda_grp.c